# How to get clone of HTML, modify it, get HTML string without affecting DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have some HTML code like this:

```
<div style="background:red;width:900px;height:200px" id="wrap">
    <div id="inner" style="width:300px;float:left">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to:

1) Remove "styles" attribute and maybe some others

2) Leave only "id" attribute

4) Get resulting HTML as a string

5) **All of this without affecting the original markup**

I have tried cloning them as javascript object, but manipulations on them affect DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [clone](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/clone) your `#wrap` element, modify the as you desire, and append it to a new element, that doesn't exists on the DOM:

```
var cloned = $('#wrap').clone(), 
   container = $('<div></div>'); 

cloned.find('div').andSelf().removeAttr('style'); 

alert(container.append(cloned).html());
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/ejodu).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you had the right approach, clone-and-alter should definitely work. I don't know why your code was altering the original DOM, but this doesn't:

```
var el= document.getElementById('wrap');
el= el.cloneNode(true);
el.removeAttribute('style');
el.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].removeAttribute('style');

// Get full markup (like outerHTML, but better-supported)
//
var outer= document.createElement('div');
outer.appendChild(el);
alert(outer.innerHTML);
```